# null check nested objects before using SelectMany

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have list of `Countries` and inside it have list of `Places`.

```
// ...

public IList<ICountriesDTO> Countries { get; set; }
public class CountriesDTO: ICountriesDTO
{
    public IEnumerable<IPlacesDTO> Places { get; set; 
}
```

I am trying to get list of `Places` that are not `null`.

```
allPlacesDTO.World.Countries
    .SelectMany(x => x.Places == null ? null : x.Places)
    .ToList();
```

But I receive a `null exception` when `Places` are `null` for their `Countries` `object`.

How can I do a `null` check for `Places` and just use `return` statement instead of doing select to `null object`, similar to what I have below?

```
  if (allPlacesDTO.World.Countries.Places == null)
  {
      return;
  }
```

---

#### Update:

My requirement was if there is no places in any of the countries just use the `return` statement to exit the current function without proceeding further. That was achieved by the accepted answer and `Count` function.

```
 var lstAllPlaces = allPlacesDTO.World.Countries
    .Where(x => x.Places != null)
    .SelectMany(x => x.Places)
    .ToList();

 if (lstAllPlaces.Count() == 0)
 {
     return;
 }
```

Comment: The edit is not clear - when one Country has Places==null, do you want the places from  a) all other countries, b) only the countries before that or c) no countries ?

Comment: The Update: still is not clear, how and where do your fit an `if(){}` in that SelectMany?

Comment: @Henk Holterman ,  Sorry:) . Made Small typo in hurry. Fixed the update. Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do the condition in where clause

```
allPlacesDTO.World.Countries.Where(x => x.Places != null)
                            .SelectMany(x => x.Places).ToList();
```

Or change the ternary operator to return new List() (it can be greedy)